# Laravel detect if there is a new item in an array

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I want to implement a system in my project that "alerts" users when there is a new comment on one of their posts.

I currently query all comments on the posts from the logged in user and put everything in an array and send it to my view.

Now my goal is to make an alert icon or something when there is a new item in this array. It doesn't have to be live with ajax just on page load is already good :)

So I've made a function in my UsersController where I get the comments here's my code

```
public function getProfileNotifications()
{
$uid = Auth::user()->id;
$projects = User::find($uid)->projects;
//comments
if (!empty($projects)) {
            foreach ($projects as $project) {
                    $comments_collection[] = $project->comments;
                }
            }

            if (!empty($comments_collection)) {
                $comments = array_collapse($comments_collection);

                foreach($comments as $com)
                {   
                    if ($com->from_user != Auth::user()->id) {
                        $ofdate = $com->created_at;
                        $commentdate = date("d M", strtotime($ofdate));
                        $comarr[] = array(
                                          'date' => $ofdate,
                                          $commentdate,User::find($com->from_user)->name,
                                          User::find($com->from_user)->email,
                                          Project::find($com->on_projects)->title,
                                          $com->on_projects,
                                          $com->body,
                                          Project::find($com->on_projects)->file_name,
                                          User::find($com->from_user)->file_name
                                         );
                    }    
                }
} else {
                $comarr = "";
}
}
```

Is there a way I can check on page load if there are new items in the array? Like keep a count and then do a new count and subtract the previous count from the new one?

Is this even a good way to apprach this?

Many thanks in advance! Any help is appreciated.

### EDIT

so I added a field unread to my table and I try to count the number of unreads in my comments array like this:

```
$uid = Auth::user()->id;
$projects = User::find($uid)->projects;
//comments
if (!empty($projects)) {
    foreach ($projects as $project) {
        $comments_collection[] = $project->comments;
    }
}    

$unreads = $comments_collection->where('unread', 1);
dd($unreads->count());
```

But i get this error:

Call to a member function where() on array

Anyone any idea how I can fix this?

Comment: 1. Keep track of the most recent `$com->created_at` 
2. On each request, if a comment has a newer `created_at` than the session variable, it's new!

Comment: @jszobody hey what exactly do you mean by "keep track of the most recent $com->created_at"?

Comment: @jszobody I don't understand how you can compare the most recent created_at with the most recent one before the page reload. I hope it makes sense what I'm trying to say :)

Comment: @Cruzito, well you'd need to use ajax calls with the current created_at to see if there is a newer one available or you'd have to use a session variable like jszobody suggested.  Read up on session flashing.

Comment: @Devon I don't realy have much experience with ajax that's why it is fine if it happens on page load. I thought this may be a workaround the ajax :)

Answer (score 2):

The "standard" way of doing this is to track whether the comment owner has "read" the comment. You can do that fairly easily by adding a "unread" (or something equivalent) flag.

When you build your models, you should [define all their relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships) so that stuff like this becomes relatively easy.

If you do not have relationships, you need to define something like the following:

*In User*

```
public function projects()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Project');
}
```

*In Project*

```
public function comments()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Comment');
}
```

Once you hav ethose relationshipt, you can do the following. Add filtering as you see fit.

```
$count = $user->projects()
              ->comments()
              ->where('unread', true)
              ->count();
```

This is then the number you display to the user. When they perform an action you think means they've acknowledged the comment, you dispatch an asynchronous request to mark the comment as read. A REST-ish way to do this might look something like the following:

*Javascript, using JQuery:*

```
jQuery.ajax( '/users/{userId}/projects/{projectId}/comments/{commentId}', {
    method: 'patch'
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {
        'unread': false
    }
})
```

*PHP, in patch method:*

```
$comment = Comment::find($commentId);
$comment->update($patchData);
```

Keep in mind you can use [Laravel's RESTful Resource Controllers](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/controllers#restful-resource-controllers) to provide this behavior.

Comment: I'm sorry but looks very complicated I'm just not gonna implement the feature I thought it was gonna be simple lol :) thanks anyways

Comment: I tried your method and detected a problem I actualy dont store the user_id in my comments table I only store the project id and the userid of the one who commented. the way i get the comments now is I get all projects from the logged in user and from these projects i get all comments

Comment: @Cruzito Just so you're aware, you should post different questions as a new question.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$unreads = $project->comments()->where('unread', 1);
dd($unreads->count());
```

**EDIT**

My be [Has Many Through](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through) relation will fit your needs

User.php

```
public function comments()
{
    return $this->hasManyTrough('App\Project', 'App\Comment');
}
```

Project.php

```
public function comments()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Comment');
}
```

then you can access `comments` from user directly

```
$user->comments()->where('unread', 1)->count();
```

or I recommend you define `hasUnreadComments` method in `User`

```
public function hasUnreadComments()
{
    $return (bool) $this->comments()->where('unread', 1)->count();
}
```

P.S.

```
$uid = Auth::user()->id;
$projects = User::find($uid)->projects;
```

this code is horrible, this way much better

```
$projects = Auth::user()->projects;
```

Comment: This doesn't work unfortunately because a user can have multiple projects with mulitple comments so there needs to be a loop over the projects en per projects get the comments